# GCM, Android: Am I permitted to automatically send registration ID without asking the user?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a few questions about GCM!

In most tutorials they create a registration activity where the user registrates for a registration ID with GCM to enable push notifications. I would want to do this automatically when the user starts my app the first time, without the user having to do anything, therefore I wonder if it's allowed to do this or if I need the user's permission in some way?

I also have a more specific question about the regID. So far, I've noticed it's always been the same for my phone. How does it actually work, does every device have its very own regID that never changes? If so; then I only need to register it once, the first time the user opens my app, am I right? Or how do you guys do it? I'm storing all the registered devices' regIDs in a database, and when I want to send a notification, it sends to all the regIDs in the database. If I send the regID every time the user opens the app, the database will have the same regID a lot of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register automatically to GCM when  the app starts for the first time. You don't need to ask the user for a permission (the user gives you that permission when they install the app, since they are shown a list including all the permissions required by the app, including GCM).

Registration ID for a given app on a given device may change occasionally. Therefore Google suggest (as shown in their demo app) to register to GCM any time the app is updated. As for your DB storing the same Registration ID multiple times, you should have a smarter implementation - don't insert a registration ID if it already exists in your DB.

Comment: Thanks, nice and simple answer!